# reading row from text file into two vectors c++

Tags: c++, text-files

I am trying to read the two words "kelly 1000" in the text file "players", into vectors players and balances respectively. Don't know why it's not working?

```
string name = "kelly";
int main()
{
    int num =0;
vector<string> players;
vector<int> balances;
ifstream input_file("players.txt");
while(!input_file.eof())
{
    input_file >> players[num];
    input_file >> balances[num];
    num++;
}
for(size_t i = 0; i=players.size(); i++)
{
    if(name==players[i])
        cout << "Welcome " << name << ", your current balance is " << balances[i] <<          "$." << endl;
    else 
        break;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more how "it's not working"? Does it compile? Link? Crash when running? Some other problem?

Comment: And you should not do `while (!input_file.eof()) { ... }`, it will not work as you expect. Instead do `while (input_file >> p >> b) { ... }`

Comment: it says vector subscript out of range when I debug (at input_file >> players[num]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `operator[]` you can only access existing elements. Going out of bounds invokes undefined behaviour. Your vectors are empty and you need to use `push_back` method to add elements to them.

Second problem is `while (!file.eof())` anti-pattern. It'll typicaly loop one to many times because the read of last record doesn't neccesarily trigger `eof`. When reading from streams, *always* check whether input succeeded before you make use of values read. That's typicaly done by using `operator>>` inside loop condition.

```
string temp_s;
int temp_i;

while (input_file >> temp_s >> temp_i) {
    players.push_back(temp_s);
    balances.push_back(temp_i);
}
```

This way the loop stops if `operator>>` fails.

Comment: @Merni No, I mean it as I wrote. Did you read the first paragraph? You can't say `players[num]` on a empty vector - or in other words `num` can't be greater than `players.size()-1` (just like with plain arrays).

Answer (score 3):

```
//Hope this is something you want dear.Enjoy
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string name = "kelly";
int main()
{
    int num =0;
    string tempname;
    int tempbalance;
    vector<string> players;
    vector<int> balances;
    ifstream input_file("players.txt");
    while(!input_file.eof())
    {   input_file>>tempname;
      input_file>>tempbalance;

      players.push_back(tempname);
        balances.push_back(tempbalance);

    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i<players.size(); i++)
    {
        if(name==players.at(i))
            cout<< "Welcome " << name << ", your current balance is " << balances.at(i)<<          "$." << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```